# Aligning an array in align*

Tags: align, arrays

I was trying to make a 3 point list with a brace next to 2 of the items with text next to it and than a brace that covered all three again with text next to it. I had never used an array before but I found an example of something similar to what I had in mind on this website which did use one. I fiddled around with it a bit and ended up with something that did what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left. \begin{array}{l}
\left. \begin{array}{l}
1.\text{ Mensen hebben tegengestelde oordelen.} \\
2.\text{ Elke keuze is arbitrair.} \\
\end{array}\right\} \text{Scepticisme of fenemonalisme.}\\
\hspace{0.22cm}3.\text{ Waarneming is inzicht dus is scepticisme fout.}\\ 
\end{array}\right\} \parbox{5cm}{Fenemonalisme is juist. \\ PNC is vals.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I'm quite pleased with the result except for \hspace. I was trying to align the numbers 1., 2. and 3. using & but wherever I put them they only generated extra linebreaks with the following error:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Without the `\hspace` everything is ok, except for the 3. being close to 0.22cm to much to the left. What's a better and more elegant way to align these?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin/end them with a greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning array elements with elements outside the array won't work. One quick solution would be to put the third item in an array just like the first two, and add an empty `\left.\right.` construct around it to get the additional spacing that is caused by that:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left. \begin{array}{l}
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
      1.\text{ Mensen hebben tegengestelde oordelen.} \\
      2.\text{ Elke keuze is arbitrair.} \\
    \end{array}\right\}%
      \text{Scepticisme of fenemonalisme.}\\
    \left.\begin{array}{l}
      3.\text{ Waarneming is inzicht dus is scepticisme fout.}
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right\}%
  \parbox{5cm}{%
    Fenemonalisme is juist.\\
    PNC is vals.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```